# jhipster refresh url cause "Cannot GET /user-management"

Tags: angular, jhipster, angular5, yarnpkg

I create a jhipster app successfully, then login with admin/admin, click user-management, all works, the url changes to localhost:9000/user-management.

However, when I refresh url using chrome refresh button, the page broken with message: "Cannot GET /user-management", after press F12 to launch debugger, it has below error message in console:

Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-GKWAMtgBzlCzmucztJIeDl/kD0MKNqAT5HDcFIff2+A='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note also that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

Please help, thanks in advance.

Note: yarn v1.3.2, "@angular/core": "5.2.0", java 1.8, jwt, elastic search, Chinese, mysql, angular 5

Comment: Your url looks  strange as it does not include a `#`

Comment: I set useHash: false, because I want to support both www.xxx.com and www.xxx.com/admin, let user input # seems strange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set `useHash: false` and click on refresh, the request is sent to the server so you get this exact error you had: a client route being processed by server and not found. So you must adapt the server side using a servlet filter, see details in https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/4794#issuecomment-304097246

Please note also that this approach does not easily work for gateways in microservices architecture.

Here is an example of such a filter that you can adapt and which forwards requests for client routes to '/' so that they get interpreted by the angular app in index.html:

```java
public class AngularRouteFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    // add the values you want to redirect for
    private static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("^/((api|swagger-ui|management|swagger-resources)/|favicon\\.ico|v2/api-docs).*");

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                                    HttpServletResponse response,
                                    FilterChain filterChain)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
        if (isServerRoute(request)) {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        } else {
            RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/");
            rd.forward(request, response);
        }
    }

    protected static boolean isServerRoute(HttpServletRequest request) {
        if (request.getMethod().equals("GET")) {
            String uri = request.getRequestURI();
            return PATTERN.matcher(uri).matches();
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks @Marziou, I will try this filter. Just confused, when I try official hero tutorial in angular.io (useHash: false), refreshing the url looks ok, I use fiddler to monitor the response which is "HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified".

Comment: The heroes tutorial on angular.io does not use any server API, data is not fetched from server it is hard coded in an angular service, that's why there's no need to differentiate between client and server routes. The servers only serve static assets used by client.