# Jhipster: Navigation error, no more /#/

Tags: angular, jhipster

I have successfully generated a monolithic jhipster 4.13 application and modified it to launch with a login page. 
Now all my application's url change from  "http://localhost:9000/#/" to "http://localhost:9000/". 
For example, if I call fonctionnality  and then  I will have:

```
 "http://localhost:9000/user-management/(audits)" instead of "http://localhost:9000/#/audits"
```

thus generating a page not found error!

What I am doing wrong? I need your help, thank you in advance.

Here is the content of my app.route.ts:

```
export const APP_ROUTE: Routes = [
    {
      path: '',
      component: HomeLayoutComponent,
      data: {
        authorities: ['ROLE_USER'],    // ROLE_ADMIN
        pageTitle: 'home.title'
      },
      canActivate: [ UserRouteAccessService ],
      children: [
        { path: '', component: NavbarComponent, outlet: 'navbar' },
        { path: '',
          component: HomeComponent,
          data: {
            authorities: ['ROLE_USER'],
            pageTitle: 'home.title'
          },
          canActivate: [UserRouteAccessService]
        },
        ...errorRoute,
        ...adminState,
        ...accountState
      ]
    },
    {
      path: '',
      component: LoginLayoutComponent,
      children: [
        { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
        { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
        { path: 'reset/request', component: PasswordResetInitComponent },
        { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent }
      ]
    },
    // otherwise redirect to 404 page not found
    { path: '404', component: PageNotFoundComponent },
    { path: '**', redirectTo: '404', pathMatch: 'full' }
];
```

Here is the content of the app-routing.module.ts file:

```
const LAYOUT_ROUTES = [
    navbarRoute,
    ...APP_ROUTE,    
    ...errorRoute
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(
            LAYOUT_ROUTES,
            { useHash: true, enableTracing: true }
        )
    ],
    exports: [
        RouterModule
    ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48567071/jhipster-refresh-url-cause-cannot-get-user-management

Comment: @GaëlMarziou, thanks, i've added useHash: true and the /#/  came back. But, still have: "http://localhost:9000/#/user-management/(audits)" instead of "http://localhost:9000/#/audits".

Comment: Presently I need to add a slash in the routerLink parameter (ex: routerLink="/user-managment") in order to make it work as before. What am I doing wrong?