# Webpack Undertow JHipster configuration

Tags: angular, nginx, webpack, jhipster, undertow

I have a JHipster monolith application based on Angular 5.
I am not able to replicate the configuration that I did to webpack through the webpack.dev.js file to the undertow when I compile and run under production profile.

Here are the important lines of my webpack.dev.js file:

```
module.exports = webpackMerge(commonConfig({ env: ENV }), {
    devtool: 'eval-source-map',
    devServer: {
        contentBase: './target/www',
        historyApiFallback: {
            index: '/MyApp/'
        },
        publicPath: "/MyApp/",
```

I have changed the Location strategy to a Custom one because I wanted to support both the HashLocationStrategy and the PathLocationStrategy at the same time. Plus I need the urls to be bookmarkable.
Basically emulate the paths of an MVC and old angular applicaiton that is why I do this.

```
providers: [
    { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/MyApp' },
    { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: CustomLocationStrategy },
```

and the custom location strategy:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HashLocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';

@Injectable()
export class CustomLocationStrategy extends HashLocationStrategy {
    prepareExternalUrl(internal: string): string {
        let url = this.getBaseHref() + '/#' + internal;
        if (internal === '/login') {
            url = this.getBaseHref() + internal;
        }
        return url;
    }
}
```

Now everything works ok under the development profile.
For example the http://localhost:8080/ redirects me correctly to the http://localhost:8080/MyApp/login and if I reload the  http://localhost:8080/MyApp/login I land at the same page (no 404). So these are bookmarkable as well.

But under production profile there are no proxy, history api fallback and publicPath variables.

Thus when I hit the http://localhost:8080 I receive a 404.
When I hit the localhost:8080/MyApp works ok.
When I hit the http://localhost:8060/MyApp/login I receive the:

> A parser-blocking, cross site (i.e. different eTLD+1) script,
>   https://linkhelp.clients.google.com/tbproxy/lh/wm?sourceid=wm&url=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8060%2FMyApp%2Flogin&hl=en&site=localhost%3A8060&error=http404&js=true,
>   is invoked via document.write. The network request for this script MAY
>   be blocked by the browser in this or a future page load due to poor
>   network connectivity. If blocked in this page load, it will be
>   confirmed in a subsequent console message. See
>   https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5718547946799104 for more
>   details.

and here is a screenshot:
[image]

Thus the links are not bookmarkable.
In production I am using NgInx as a reverse proxy.
Could I somehow use this in order to emulate webpack/NodeJs ?
I haven't managed yet unfortunately.
Or it is possible to do the same with the tools that I already have (undertow, webpack under the prod profile?

Any suggestions how to solve this situation would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE 2.1:
I have followed your comments Gael. I have included the filter with some additional patterns and indeed all requests give back now a 200 - OK response.
When I hit the http://localhost:8060/MyApp/login all the requests return 200 but at the console I see

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

here is a screenshot as well:
[image]

I have returned the appropriate content type as well based on the extension of the file that I return:

1. text/javascript for the js files
2. text/css for the css files
3. and text/html for all the rest

Do you have any pointers please?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you configured a servlet filter to support deep linking with PathLocationStrategy? I have already answered this on SO and provided an example of filter.

Comment: No I haven't done anything like that. I would appreciate if you could you please paste the link.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48567071/jhipster-refresh-url-cause-cannot-get-user-management and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38516667/springboot-angular2-how-to-handle-html5-urls

Comment: Hi @GaëlMarziou I removed the contextPath and I have added the filter that you said. I have also added a few more patterns. All of the resources now return 200 - OK, no 404 anymore.
Now I face the following problem when I hit the localhost:8080/MyApp/login
Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:8080/MyApp/global.9a6d5bccf16e3b824fcb.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
the same for main.9a6d5bccf16e3b824fcb.css an then 5 messages like that:
Refused to execute script from '...js' because its MIME t..

Comment: Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:8080/MyApp/app/manifest.9a6d5bccf16e3b824fcb.bundle.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

I believe this is related to the CORS but I already have this enabled
    # CORS is only enabled by default with the "dev" profile, so     
jhipster.cors.allowed-origins=*

jhipster.cors.allowed-methods=*

jhipster.cors.allowed-headers=*

jhipster.cors.exposed-headers=Authorization,Link,X-Total-Count

jhipster.cors.allow-credentials=true

jhipster.cors.max-age=1800

Comment: I believe this is related to removal of the contextPath as well. I did this in order to catch the root as well /

Comment: You should edit your question if you want help because it's hard to follow in comments.