# JHipster: problem adding simple page component to react app

Tags: reactjs, jhipster

I generated a simple monolithic JHipster application with a react frontend. To test things out I tried to create a simple route pointing to a hello-world-like page. I basically copied the home page in src/main/webapp/app/modules to a simple component called 'test', stripped out the redux jazz, and added a route to routes.tsx like so:

```
  <ErrorBoundaryRoute path="/test" component={Test} />
```

I also changed HashRouter to BrowserRouter in the import statement from 'react-router-dom' in app.tsx. Now when I start up the app with e.g. ./mvnw and go to localhost:8080/test, I just get this cryptic console error:

"Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-KpHv3zgivMSB4dPnfYfqMt2lBibsYvM36EdoBBAsfbM='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note also that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback."

I have no idea what this means. Any suggestions?

Comment: Shouldn't it use a hash in url? `http://localhost:8080/#/test`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I forgot to mention that I had replaced HashRouter with BrowserRouter, so now it imports as `import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';`. Is there anything else I need to do?

Comment: I suppose it's the same as for Angular : when you don't use hash you must also modify server side, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48567071/jhipster-refresh-url-cause-cannot-get-user-management